# Как правильно составить Linq для соединения 3-ех сущностей?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, веб-программирование

Entity framework сгенерил мне вот такие сущности по моей базе:

```
public partial class Permission
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Permission()
    {
        this.UserPermissions = new HashSet<UserPermission>();
        this.ActionTypes = new HashSet<ActionType>();
    }

    public int Permission_id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ActionType> ActionTypes { get; set; }
}
public partial class UserPermission
{
    public int UserPermission_id { get; set; }
    public int User_id { get; set; }
    public int Permission_id { get; set; }
    public int Give_User_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Remove_User_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateDel { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
public partial class ActionType
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ActionType()
    {
        this.Queues = new HashSet<Queue>();
        this.UserChangeHistories = new HashSet<UserChangeHistory>();
        this.Permissions = new HashSet<Permission>();
    }

    public int Action_id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Queue> Queues { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserChangeHistory> UserChangeHistories { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

В базе это выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно я хочу узнать имеет ли конкретный User_id права наконкретный Action_id или нет.

Попробовал вот так:

```
var result = from t1 in db.UserPermissions
             join t2 in db.Permissions on t1.Permission equals t2
             join t3 in db.ActionTypes on t2.ActionTypes equals t3
             select new { f1 = t2.Permission_id };
```

Но ему чем-то не угодил последний join...

Comment: У вас `ActionTypes` это `ICollection<ActionType>`, то есть коллекция объектов `ActionType`, связанных с одним конкретным `Permission`. И с этой точки зрения `join t3 in db.ActionTypes on t2.ActionTypes equals t3` означает "объединить с таблицей `ActionTypes` где все записи в этой таблице равны множеству `ActionTypes` объекта `Permission`", что довольно бредово :)

Comment: LINQ-запрос из ответа @Monk на мой взгляд действительно лучший и наиболее наглядный вариант.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем ожидается особенность? Хоть как получайте:

```
permissions.Any(p => p.User == user && p.Permission.ActionTypes.Any(a => a.Action_id == actionId))
```

Судя по моему опыту, работа с правами обычно самая тяжелая в базах данных, поэтому её регулярно оптимизируют - промежуточные таблицы, индексы, кеширование etc. EF тут панацеей не будет, какой запрос не пиши, на больших объемах будет проседать.

Comment: А как будет выглядеть через синтаксис запросов? Я дополнил свой вопрос моим примером, где идет ругань на последний join...

Comment: @iluxa1810 без понятия, пишу именно так.